# Access ADLS Gen2 using pem/certificate from Apache Spark

Tags: azure, apache-spark, databricks, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have an Azure SPN which allows me to read data from ADLS Gen2 using certificates (.pem) file. When I use Azure SDK, I can easily create the following object

```
from azure.identity import CertificateCredential

azure_credential = CertificateCredential(
                tenant_id=tenant_id,
                client_id=client_id,
                certificate_data=client_certificate_bytes
            )
```

and then use it to access ADLS Gen2

```
DataLakeServiceClient(
        account_url=ACCOUNT_URL,
        credential=azure_credential,
    ).get_file_system_client(blob_container_name)
```

I need to use the same SPN from Apache Spark but I cannot find a way to achieve this. As per the authentication methods written in ABFS documentation, it doesn't seem to be possible (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-azure/abfs.html#Authentication). My goal would be to set the certificate like I used to set the client secrets in Spark conf like below.

```
spark_session.conf.set("fs.adl.oauth2.access.token.provider.type", "ClientCredential")
spark_session.conf.set("fs.adl.oauth2.client.id", client_id)
spark_session.conf.set("fs.adl.oauth2.credential", client_secret)
spark_session.conf.set("fs.adl.oauth2.refresh.url", f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token")
```

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/storage/azure-storage.html), these are the ways to connect to ADLS Gen2:

1. OAuth 2.0 with an Azure service principal.
2. Shared access signatures (SAS).
3. Account keys.

What you are asking, configuring a certificate (.pem) in Spark configuration like we do for secrets, is not possible.

You can provide feedback and request this feature by following the steps in this [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/resources/ideas.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Connecting to ADLS Gen2 in Databricks: Configuration Options

According to the official [Databricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/storage/azure-storage.html), there are multiple ways to connect to Azure Data Lake Storage (ADLS) Gen2. The available methods include:

1. **OAuth 2.0 with an Azure Service Principal**
2. **Shared Access Signatures (SAS)**
3. **Account Keys**

It's important to note that configuring a certificate (.pem) directly in Spark configuration, akin to how secrets are managed, is currently not supported.

Comment: @Behroz Sikander, if you find this limitation impacting your workflow and you believe certificate configuration should be supported, you can provide feedback to Databricks through the [suggested steps](https://docs.databricks.com/en/resources/ideas.html) in their documentation.